how to unable to copy text content in website?
I want to make the text unable to be copied by users when they're in the site and same with images to make it non-downloadable too, I'm not using CSS. I code like this
 <img className="h-12 mx-auto " src={SunFog} alt="sun fog" />

I've searched and watched videos, but I didn't try anything yet.

You shouldn't. It's the most annoying feature ever and there are workarounds, always

it's required by the owner of the business, but me.. i don't care about this thing

"make it undownloadable too" — anything the web browser displays to a user is already downloaded, otherwise the browser would not be able to display it. As David said, these "security" measures don't work and just annoy people. Maybe if you said what your goal is that you think doing these things will solve. "required by the owner of the business" — sometimes it's the developer's job to tell the client what they want is not possible, feasible, or a bad idea.

i have logo images that they asked me if i can make it unable to be downloadable or copied if possible

You can make it a little bit harder for naïve users to copy/download images, but for experienced users there are easy ways to get around that. In any case if something is on the screen it can be captured by a simple screen-shot.  It is not possible to entirely prevent someone from copying resources from a website.

I would make the case with the business owner that it will cost you X to deliver a subpar feature and will actually annoy their customers to no end
